# Filter Collection by Substring in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

If I were to want to do an autocomplete for a collection, what would be the best way? I'd like to see if a search string is in any (or a select few) attributes in my model.

I was thinking something like...

```
this.collection.filter(function(model) {
    return model.values().contains($('input.search]').val());
})
```

**Edit** I'm sorry, I must not have explained it well enough. If I have a collection with attributes...

```
[ 
  { first: 'John', last: 'Doe'}, 
  { first: 'Mary', last: 'Jane'} 
]
```

I want to type in `a` into my search, catch the keyup event, and filter out `{ first: 'Mary', last: 'Jane'}`, as neither John nor Doe contains an `a`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at the model's `attributes` to do something like this...

```
var search = $('input.search]').val();
this.collection.filter(function(model) {
    return _.any(model.attributes, function(val, attr) {
        // do your comparison of the value here, whatever you need
        return ~val.indexOf(search);
    });;
});
```

Comment: Am I blind? I don't see `_.any` anywhere in the documentation. http://underscorejs.org _edit_ Oh, alias of `_.some`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to filter and compare values. Backbone has an inbuilt method `where` which fetches a subset of models from the collection.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

```
var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});
```

Comment: I had the other answer here so far, but I'm totally upvoting yours... Didn't know about that feature! :)

Comment: But I'm implementing the feature in the vein as an autocomplete. I want to type and have it immediately filter. So I'm looking for Musketeer, I type "Musk" I want it to work. Also, I want it to search across several, if not all, attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You want `model` items in your `collection` such that any of the values `v` contain your search text `q`. That translates to the following.

```
var q = $('input.search').val();
this.collection.filter(function(model) {
    return _.any(model.values(), function(v) {
        return ~v.indexOf(q);
    });
})
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for. Is `string.contains()` supported in all browsers? Why have I been using `string.indexOf()`?

Comment: @savinger Because there is no `contains` method. :) I had just copied what the OP had written without thinking about it.

Comment: Well, actually, there is! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains And I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: See the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains#Browser_compatibility) section...

Comment: It is supported in Chrome, just tested it. But I'll use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this... case insensitive, substring matching for a subset of my model attributes.

```
var search = $(e.currentTarget).val().toLowerCase();
this.collection.filter(function(model) {
  return _.some(
    [ model.get('first'), model.get('last') ], 
    function(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1;
    });
 });
```